# Changing Match's Status Depending On Time (Fail When it's over the mid night 00:00 )

Tags: java, android

I've an app that contains items, each item contain a time and a status .
the status is based on time, it takes the items form a Json, the time is a match time, and the status is the match's status (Soccer). Now let me explain it.

Example for item :

> Local (Device) Date : 22:00, 2016/4/28.
>
> Match Date : 23:00, 2016/4/28 .
>
> Match Status : Didn't Start Yet.

Now, When the local time is "23:00", the status will be " First Half ", when it's "23:45", the status will be "Halftime Break", When it's over "00:00", the status will revert back to "Didn't Start Yet" .

My logic for this is as the following :

1. Check If it's the match date (day/month/year).
2. True? check the time, (I'm conveting time to Millis, in long type ), based on comparing i'm setting the status .

But, the problem when it's over 00:00 it will revert back to the original status ( didn't start yet ), because the condifion "if it's the day" will be false .

Any ideas for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this soccer match has a fixed time limit and can't last more than a day, I think you could make it work with a special case checking for the next day and the length of the game so far.  Take this as **psuedocode**:

```
long maxLengthOfGame = 5400000;

bool sameDay = matchDate.day() == localDate.day();
bool afterStartTime = localDate.time() >= matchDate.time();

bool nextDay = matchDate.day()+1 == localDate.day();
bool lengthOfCurrentGame = midnight - mathDate.time() + localDate.time();
bool withinTimeLimit = lengthOfCurrentGame < maxLengthOfGame;

if ((sameDay && afterStartTime) || (nextDay && withinTimeLimit)) {
    // Code here
}
```